# lightning:button refreshes my page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to use a standard way of showing a button that executes a javascript.

I am trying to use:

```
<lightning:button label="Execute Javascript" onclick="{!c.executeJavascript}" />
```

It displays nicely, but on every click on the button, the page refreshes, and this is not the behavior that I need.

When I look at the generated html I can see that a `<button>`  is generated, but without the `type` attribute. This attribute defaults to "submit" so I believe this is why my page is refreshing after clicking.

For now I use plain html to show the button and it is ok.

Is this a bug / feature?

Is there a way to set the type for the button that `<lightning:button>` generates?

**Update**

this is the code I a using:

```
<aura:component access="GLOBAL" controller="cont">
    <div class="slds">
           <lightning:card iconName="standard:report" title="myTitle">

            <aura:set attribute="actions">
                <lightning:button label="Upload Report" onclick="{!c.openReport}" />
            </aura:set>

        </lightning:card>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Update2**

The component 'c:myComp' is wrapped by a Lightning app 'c:myComp_app':

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:myComp"/>
</aura:application>
```

And is implemented inside a VisualForce page through Lightning out:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="cont" cache="true">

    <apex:includeLightning />

    <apex:composition template="my_Template">
        <apex:define name="body">
            <div id="lex_id" />
        </apex:define>
    </apex:composition>

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:myComp_app", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:myComp",
                {  },
                "lex_id",
                function(cmp) {
                    // do some stuff
                    console.log('component created');
                    console.log(cmp);
            });
        });
    </script>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: is the button inside `<form />` tag?. If so, remove the form tag and try it

Comment: no '<form>' tag, I have updated my question with the component markup

Comment: I don't have the issue, and when I look at the code I don't have the type attribute so I guess I have the same code generated. Where are you using your component ?

Comment: I show it now inside a VisualForce page using lightning out

Comment: @ItaiShmida Does the lightning component embedded inside a div wrapped in `apex:form` tag visualforce. Also please update the question which details exact scenario to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It is not inside '<apex:form>' - I have included the visualforce page and lightning app